# Total derivative of implicit functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-differentiation

If we have three implicit functions as following:
$$f(x,y,z)=0$$
$$g(x,t)=0$$
$$M(x,y)=0$$
First, if I want to compute the derivative of z w.r.t x , will it be as following?
$$\frac{dz}{dx}=z_x+z_y\frac{dy}{dx}$$
where 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{M_x}{M_y}$$
$$z_x=-\frac{f_x}{f_z}$$
$$z_y=-\frac{f_y}{f_z}$$
I think this is wrong because we can solve it using this formula only if z is an explicit function of x and y, but here it is an implicit function... So how can we compute the derivative of z w.r.t. x if this formula should not be applied here?

Second, if I want to compute the derivative of z w.r.t. t :
my trial is as following
$$\frac{dz}{dt}=(z_x+z_y\frac{dy}{dx})\frac{dx}{dt}$$
where $$\frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac{g_t}{g_x}$$
But also I think this wrong solution for the same reason.. So how can we solve this if my answer is wrong?